# Codeigniter strips characters from HTML Email

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, email

I have developed a CMS and when user forgets his/her password / the system will generate a new random password and send it to the user through email but when i open the email it automatically strip some character from my email body replacing them with (=).

This is the email after its sent you can see the messed up parts in bold

Dear Noor Shirzai This Email was **se=t** to you in order to inform you that your Password has **be=n** reset.
Bellow is your New Password :
Your Username is : mohib
Your New **Pas=word** is : IOODiGhcYYrL
Please change your **<=trong>** New Password as soon as you login to the system in order **to=avoid** any security issues.

**Note :** when i send this with Pure PHP mail function it works fine.

bellow is my email function and the email configuration file code:

I will really appreciate any help that i get. 
thanks

my function that send the mail:

```
if (! function_exists('send_password'))
{
    function send_password($user_info, $password)
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();

        $username           = $user_info['username'];
        $name               = $user_info['firstname'].' '.$user_info['lastname'];
        $email              = $user_info['email'];

        $subject            = 'Your New Password : Noor CMS |'.$CI->config->item('site_name');
        //email body
        $message            = '';

        $message            .= '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">';
        $message            .= '<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">';
        $message            .= '<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-type">';
        $message            .= '<head>';
        $message            .= '<title> Your New Password : Noor CMS | '.$CI->config->item('site_name').' </title>';
        $message            .= '</head>';
        $message            .= '<body>';
        $message            .= 'Dear '.trim($name);
        $message            .= 'This Email was sent to you in order to inform you that your <strong>Password</strong> has been reset.<br/>';
        $message            .= 'Bellow is your <strong> New Password :</strong><br/>';
        $message            .= 'Your <strong>Username </strong>is : <strong> '.trim($username).'</strong><br/>';
        $message            .= 'Your <strong>New Password </strong>is : <strong> '.trim($password).'</strong><br/>';
        $message            .= 'Please change your <strong>New Password</strong> as soon as you login to the system in order to avoid any security issues.<br/>';
        $message            .= '</body></html>';

        //prepare email and send
        $CI->email->from($CI->config->item('admin_email'), $CI->config->item('admin_name'));
        $CI->email->to($email);
        $CI->email->subject($subject);
        $CI->email->message($message);

        if ($CI->email->send())
        {
            return TRUE;
        }

        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

And the email.php config file is as follows:

```
$config['useragent']            = 'NoorCMS';
$config['protocol']         = 'mail';
$config['mailpath']         = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
$config['smtp_host']            = '';
$config['smtp_user']            = '';
$config['smtp_pass']            = '';
$config['smtp_port']            = 25;
$config['smtp_timeout']         = 10;
$config['wordwrap']         = FALSE;
$config['wrapchars']            = 100;
$config['mailtype']         = 'html';
$config['send_multipart']       = FALSE;
$config['charset']          = 'utf-8';
$config['validate']         = FALSE;
$config['priority']         = 1;
$config['crlf']             = '\n';
$config['newline']          = '\n';
$config['bcc_batch_mode']   = FALSE;
$config['bcc_batch_size']       = 200;
```

Comment: If the links don't provided don't help, then it may be a matter of line length.

Answer (score 7):

I had this problem - you need to update your email config:

```
$config['newline']  = "\r\n";
$config['crlf'] = "\r\n";
```

Comment: My colleague pointed this solution to me. I was missing the `clrf` config. 

Why `clrf`?
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php : `Each line should be separated with a CRLF (\r\n). Lines should not be larger than 70 characters.`

Answer (score 0):

To try cutting down the line length, do this:

```
    $message            = array();

    $message[] = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">';
    $message[] = '<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">';
    $message[] = '<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-type">';
    $message[] = '<head>';
    $message[] = '<title> Your New Password : Noor CMS | '.$CI->config->item('site_name').' </title>';
    $message[] = '</head>';
    $message[] = '<body>';
    $message[] = 'Dear '.trim($name);
    $message[] = 'This Email was sent to you in order to inform you that your <strong>Password</strong> has been reset.<br/>';
    $message[] = 'Bellow is your <strong> New Password :</strong><br/>';
    $message[] = 'Your <strong>Username </strong>is : <strong> '.trim($username).'</strong><br/>';
    $message[] = 'Your <strong>New Password </strong>is : <strong> '.trim($password).'</strong><br/>';
    $message[] = 'Please change your <strong>New Password</strong> as soon as you login to the system in order to avoid any security issues.<br/>';
    $message[] = '</body></html>';

    $message = implode(PHP_EOL, $message);
```